# Is there a foreach loop in Go?

Tags: go, foreach, slice

Is there a `foreach` construct in the Go language?
Can I iterate over a slice or array using a `for`?

Comment: check out: http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/e2966ccdfe910e14?pli=1

Comment: The usage of `range` in `for` loops is also mentioned in the "An Interlude about Types" section (towards its end) of the Go tutorial.

Answer (score 1123, accepted):

From *[For statements with range clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range)*:

> A "for" statement with a "range" clause iterates through all entries
> of an array, slice, string or map, or values received on a channel.
> For each entry it assigns iteration values to corresponding iteration
> variables and then executes the block.

As an example:

```golang
for index, element := range someSlice {
    // index is the index where we are
    // element is the element from someSlice for where we are
}
```

If you don't care about the index, you can use `_`:

```golang
for _, element := range someSlice {
    // element is the element from someSlice for where we are
}
```

The underscore, `_`, is the [*blank identifier*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier), an anonymous placeholder.

Comment: In this example, `element` is the *value* of the element (a copy) -- it is not the element itself.  Although you can assign to `element`, this will not effect the underlying sequence.

Comment: I know in Python and C it's frequent to use underscore as a function for localization ( i.e. the [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#localizing-your-module) ). Would the use of underscore cause any problems in Go ? Does Go even use the same library for localization ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Py docs says "(gettext) function is usually aliased as `_()` in the local namespace" which is just _by convention_, it's not part of the localization lib. The underscore `_` is a valid label, and it's also convention in Go (and Python and Scala and other langs) to assign to `_` for return values you won't use. The scope of `_` in this example is restricted to the body of the `for` loop. If you have a package-scoped function `_` then it would be shadowed inside the scope of the for loop. There's a few packages for localization, I've not seen any use `_` as a function name.

Comment: See [Moshe Revah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333832/1365918) below for more usage examples of `for...range`. Includes slices, maps and channels.

Answer (score 228):

Go has a `foreach`-like syntax. It supports arrays/slices, maps and channels.

Iterate over an **array** or a **slice**:

```
// index and value
for i, v := range slice {}

// index only
for i := range slice {}

// value only
for _, v := range slice {}
```

Iterate over a **map**:

```
// key and value
for key, value := range theMap {}

// key only
for key := range theMap {}

// value only
for _, value := range theMap {}
```

Iterate over a **channel**:

```
for v := range theChan {}
```

Iterating over a channel is equivalent to receiving from a channel until it is closed:

```
for {
    v, ok := <-theChan
    if !ok {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Although the OP only asked for slice usage, I prefer this answer, because most will eventually need the other usages as well.

Comment: important distinction about the `chan` usage: ranging over a channel will gracefully exit the loop if the writer closes the channel at some point. In the `for {v := <-theChan}` _equivalent_, it will *not* exit on channel close. You can test for this via the second `ok` return value. [TOUR EXAMPLE](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4)

Comment: Thought the same when reading it, `for { ... }` stands for an infinite loop.

Comment: How about just for without both key, value.I just want to run specific len. And do nothing with array. Ex: for _ := range slice{}

Answer (score 24):

Following is the example code for how to use *foreach* in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    arrayOne := [3]string{"Apple", "Mango", "Banana"}

    for index,element := range arrayOne{

        fmt.Println(index)
        fmt.Println(element)

    }

}
```

This is a running example https://play.golang.org/p/LXptmH4X_0

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest example that is the most useful. Thanks! I've got nothing against the most esoteric answers from the other commenters — they certainly illustrate the intricacies of very idiomatic Go programming, to the point that they become... unreadable and hard to follow — but I prefer your answer: it goes straight to the core with the simplest possible example (which works and it's obvious why it works).

Answer (score 16):

Yes, ***range***:

The range form of the *for* loop iterates over a slice or map.

When ranging over a slice, two values are returned for each iteration. The first is the index, and the second is a copy of the element at that index.

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var pow = []int{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128}

func main() {
    for i, v := range pow {
        fmt.Printf("2**%d = %d\n", i, v)
    }

    for i := range pow {
        pow[i] = 1 << uint(i) // == 2**i
    }
    for _, value := range pow {
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", value)
    }
}
```

- You can skip the index or value by assigning to `_`.
- If you only want the index, drop the `,` value entirely.

Answer (score 13):

The following example shows how to use the `range` operator in a `for` loop to implement a `foreach` loop.

```
func PrintXml (out io.Writer, value interface{}) error {
    var data []byte
    var err error

    for _, action := range []func() {
        func () { data, err = xml.MarshalIndent(value, "", "  ") },
        func () { _, err = out.Write([]byte(xml.Header)) },
        func () { _, err = out.Write(data) },
        func () { _, err = out.Write([]byte("\n")) }} {
        action();
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The example iterates over an array of functions to unify the error handling for the functions. A complete example is at Google´s [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4gWycXk5yX).

PS: it shows also that hanging braces are a bad idea for the readability of code. Hint: the `for` condition ends just before the `action()` call. Obvious, isn't it?

Comment: Add a `,` and it's clearer where the `for` condition ends: http://play.golang.org/p/pcRg6WdxBd - This is actually the first time I've found a counter argument to the `go fmt` style, thanks!

Comment: @topskip both are go fmt valid; just pick the best one :)

Comment: @FilipHaglund It is not the point if it is valid. The point is that IMO it's clearer where the for condition ends in that particular case above.

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is unreasonably complex for the targeted question.

Comment: @AndreasHassing How to do it instead without introducing redundancy?

Answer (score 12):

You can in fact use `range` without referencing its return values by using `for range` against your type:

```go
arr := make([]uint8, 5)
i,j := 0,0
for range arr {
    fmt.Println("Array Loop", i)
    i++
}

for range "bytes" {
    fmt.Println("String Loop", j)
    j++
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XHrHLbJMEd

Comment: Good to know but that's not going to be useful in most cases

Comment: Agreed @Sridhar it's pretty niche.

Answer (score 1):

This may be obvious, but you can inline the array like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for _, element := range [3]string{"a", "b", "c"} {
        fmt.Print(element)
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
abc
```

https://play.golang.org/p/gkKgF3y5nmt

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing a lot of examples using range.  Just a heads up that range creates a copy of whatever you're iterating over.  If you make changes to the contents in a foreach range you will not be changing the values in the original container, in that case you'll need a traditional for loop with an index you increment and deference indexed reference.  E.g.:

```
for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
    element := &arr[i]
    element.Val = newVal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented this library: https://github.com/jose78/go-collection.

This is an example of how to use the *Foreach* loop:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    col "github.com/jose78/go-collection/collections"
)

type user struct {
    name string
    age  int
    id   int
}

func main() {
    newList := col.ListType{user{"Alvaro", 6, 1}, user{"Sofia", 3, 2}}
    newList = append(newList, user{"Mon", 0, 3})

    newList.Foreach(simpleLoop)

    if err := newList.Foreach(simpleLoopWithError); err != nil{
        fmt.Printf("This error >>> %v <<< was produced", err )
    }
}

var simpleLoop col.FnForeachList = func(mapper interface{}, index int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d.- item:%v\n", index, mapper)
}


var simpleLoopWithError col.FnForeachList = func(mapper interface{}, index int) {
    if index > 1{
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Error produced with index == %d\n", index))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d.- item:%v\n", index, mapper)
}
```

The result of this execution should be:

```
0.- item:{Alvaro 6 1}
1.- item:{Sofia 3 2}
2.- item:{Mon 0 3}
0.- item:{Alvaro 6 1}
1.- item:{Sofia 3 2}
Recovered in f Error produced with index == 2

ERROR: Error produced with index == 2
This error >>> Error produced with index == 2
 <<< was produced
```

[Try this code in playGrounD](https://play.golang.org/p/8Hd_K3HqjRk).

Comment: How is it a for-each loop? Isn't it just list processing? Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63549127/edit) in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)